# Add things before and after in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like the code for a batch script to edit Del.bat based on a text file we will call it removelist.txt

So I want edit.bat to create del.bat taking the input from removelist.txt and putting it in the format at the bottom.

Removelist.txt

```
name 1
NaMe 2
Name3
Name 4
name 5
name 6
```

Then based on this Removelist.txt contents I want it to create Del.bat
Del.bat will always have type %~dp0\input.txt as input and %~dp0\output.log as output
So I want it to ideally come out looking like this after processing.

```
 type %~dp0\input | findstr /v "name 1" | findstr /v "NaMe 2" | findstr /v "Name3" | findstr /v "Name 4" | findstr /v "name 5" | findstr /v "name 6" > %~dp0\output.log"
```

This will create a massive delete word list expect that there could be 500+ | findstr /v "xxxxx"

Comment: OK. What is your question?

Comment: I would like to know what code I would use in my batch file to make the above things happen. I want a batch file to make another batch file using the criteria I mentioned.

Comment: Then [edit] your post and ask a specific question there. You've made a statement of what you want, but this is a "question and answer" site. You have to first ask a question before you can get an answer. What **specific part** of what you want to do are you having difficulties with that you'd like us to help you solve?

Comment: I am not sure how to go about doing this at all, I have very little experience with batch text manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "write=<nul set/p"
(%write%=type "%~dp0input"

for /f %%a in (removelist.txt) do (
    %write%= ^|Findstr /v "%%a" 
)
echo(^> "%~dp0output.log"
)>del.bat
```

This isn't exactly basic. It uses a trick with set /p to concatenate all of the text on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

`DEL.bat` is a very bad name to choose, since `DEL` is a `CMD` internal keyword.

```
FINDSTR /L /v /g:removelist.txt input >output.log
```

is all you need - I'll leave you to fix the filenames.